# Zend form for registration with salt

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a simple registration form and the password hashed using md5 encryption and a salt, I am getting an error saying that the "uni" field can not be null and I am assuming this is due to the fact that I am unsure how to add the $salt into the form(would it not be a hidden element? Like the id field?). I have done the model below:

```
public function addUser($first_name, $surname, $email, $username, $password, $salt, $age, $gender, $uni) {

    $salt=substr(md5(mt_rand()),0,20);
    $md5Password=md5($salt.$password);

    $data = array(
        'first_name' => $first_name,
        'surname' => $surname,
        'email' => $email,
        'username' => $username,
        'salt' => $salt,
        'password' => $md5Password,
        'age' => $age,
        'gender' => $gender,
        'uni' => $uni,
    );
    $this->insert($data);
}
```

and here is the form:

```
<?php

class Application_Form_Register extends Zend_Form
{


    public function init() {
        $this->setName('register');
        $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
  $id->addFilter('Int');
        $first_name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('first_name');
        $first_name->setLabel('Firstname:')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->addFilter('StripTags')
                ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
        $surname = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('surname');
        $surname->setLabel('Surname:')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->addFilter('StripTags')
                ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
    $email->setLabel('Email:')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
    $username->setLabel('Username:')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
    $password->setLabel('Password:')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    $salt = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('salt');
    $age = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('age');
    $age->setLabel('Age:')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    $gender = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('gender');
    $gender->setLabel('Gender:')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    $uni = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('uni');
    $uni->setLabel('University:')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton');
    $this->addElements(array($id, $first_name, $surname, $email, $username, $password, $salt, $age, $gender, $uni, $submit));
}
}
```

Thanks

Rik

Answer (score 0):

first 'uni' is a form field.

```
$uni = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('uni');
    $uni->setLabel('University:')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
```

this error occurs when you are passing a 'null' value to the db table column that has been declared 'not null'. To solve this, pass a 'not null' value to your 'addUser()' method, set a default value for 'uni' in your method api or allow the db table 'uni' column to accept 'null' values.

Personally I usually pass an array to these kinds on methods and then pull out the bits I want. Something like:

```
public function addStation(array $data) {
        $data = array(
            'station' => $data['station'],
            'comment' => $data['comment']
        );

        $this->insert($data);
    }
```

Again Personally I would not put the salt field in the form at all I would assign the salt in the model. No sense showing the world anything at all about my salt.

good luck.

Comment: yeah but uni shouldn't be null, and it wasn't null I entered data into the field..

Comment: check the posted data, somewhere you lost the 'uni' data. Nothing looks obviously wrong with the code you supplied. Maybe dump the $form variable in the controller and make sure everything is getting there.

Comment: sorry it was a stupid mistake on my part I was missing out a column in the db so I was inserting 8 in the model when there is 9 in total..